# Advice to implement a search for a big table

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, regex

I've created a table in asp.net (with Gridview) and it's expected to have lots of rows. There's also pagination and because I didn't want the page to refresh every time the user use it, everything go through Javascript.

Now I want to implement a search option with regex support but I'm not sure what the best way is to do it. I need the search on all the rows (not only the rows of the current page).

I'm not sure if it's possible to use regex in an sql query (I searched a bit on Google but didn't really find anything recent that helped me). The other option would be to query all the rows and filter them on the server but I'm afraid it will slow things down when we have like 2000 rows.

What would you do? Is there another option I didn't think of?

Comment: Try using data sets, it is disconnected architecture then dont try to embed the regex in SQL query, SQL wont understand regex strings, better to translate it to something meaningful before building up your ad hoc query

Comment: 2000 rows is nothing to worry about

Comment: What do you mean by "better to translate it to something meaningful" ?